# How to read from another GPU device?

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu

I want to run the following simple code on two GPUs simultaneously. Here I have a variable A[i]=[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9] and want to calculate C[i]=A[i+1]+A[i]+A[i-1]. This is the answer: C[i]=[**1** 3 6 9 **7 11** 18 21 24 **17**]. Bold numbers are wrong. For two devices, C[4] from device=1 needs to access to A[5] from device=2. How can I do it in the simplest way?

My expertise is not programming and I suppose to use multiGPU to solve a PDE equation. So, I really appreciate any help to modify this code for my current problem.

Thank you.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

__global__ void iKernel(float *A, float *C, const int N)
{
    int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    if (i < N) C[i] = A[i-1] + A[i] + A[i+1];
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int ngpus;

    printf("> starting %s", argv[0]);

    cudaGetDeviceCount(&ngpus);
    printf(" CUDA-capable devices: %i\n", ngpus);

    ngpus = 2;

    int size = 10;

    int    iSize = size / ngpus;
    size_t iBytes = iSize * sizeof(float);

    printf("> total array size %d M, using %d devices with each device "
        "handling %d M\n", size / 1024 / 1024, ngpus, iSize / 1024 / 1024);


    // allocate device memory
    float **d_A = (float **)malloc(sizeof(float *) * ngpus);
    float **d_C = (float **)malloc(sizeof(float *) * ngpus);

    float **h_A = (float **)malloc(sizeof(float *) * ngpus);
    float **gpuRef = (float **)malloc(sizeof(float *) * ngpus);
    cudaStream_t *stream = (cudaStream_t *)malloc(sizeof(cudaStream_t) * ngpus);

    for (int i = 0; i < ngpus; i++){
        // set current device
        cudaSetDevice(i);

        // allocate device memory
        cudaMalloc((void **)&d_A[i], iBytes);
        cudaMalloc((void **)&d_C[i], iBytes);

        // allocate page locked host memory for asynchronous data transfer
        cudaMallocHost((void **)&h_A[i], iBytes);
        cudaMallocHost((void **)&gpuRef[i], iBytes);

        // create streams for timing and synchronizing
        cudaStreamCreate(&stream[i]);
    }

    dim3 block(512);
    dim3 grid((iSize + block.x - 1) / block.x);

    //h_A[ngpus][index]
    for (int i = 0; i < ngpus; i++){
        cudaSetDevice(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < iSize; j++){
            h_A[i][j] = j + i*iSize;
            printf("%d %d %d %0.8f \n", i,j,iSize, h_A[i][j]);
        }
    }
    // record start time
    double iStart = clock();

    // distributing the workload across multiple devices
    for (int i = 0; i < ngpus; i++){
        cudaSetDevice(i);

        cudaMemcpyAsync(d_A[i], h_A[i], iBytes, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, stream[i]);

        iKernel << <grid, block, 0, stream[i] >> >(d_A[i], d_C[i], iSize);

        cudaMemcpyAsync(gpuRef[i], d_C[i], iBytes, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost,
            stream[i]);
    }

    // synchronize streams
    for (int i = 0; i < ngpus; i++){
        cudaSetDevice(i);
        cudaStreamSynchronize(stream[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < ngpus; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < iSize; j++){
            printf("%d %d %0.8f \n", i,j,gpuRef[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: In your kernel, what do you expect the behavior to be when `i=0` ?  What do you expect the code should do when accessing `A[i-1]` if `i=0` ?  To be clear, I don't think this question that I am asking has much of anything to do with CUDA.  I'm not suggesting that is the only issue with your code. Another thing I would suggest is that you demonstrate the use of proper CUDA error checking and also run your code with `cuda-memcheck`. The error output may be instructive for you, and useful for those who are trying to help you. Finally, you may wish to review the CUDA simpleMultiGPU sample code.

Comment: Robert, Thank you for your quick reply. I know for i=0 and i=9, kernel needs to be modified. But my main problem is C[4] and C[5] which are located on the boundary of each device.

Comment: As described in the answer, you have a few options.  1. Use pinned allocations instead of `cudaMalloc`.  2. Use managed memory  3. Explicitly copy boundary regions between GPUs in between kernel launches.  4. If system topology supports, put both GPUs into a peer relationship.  Then the kernel on one GPU can read directly from the memory of the other GPU, over the intervening bus (PCIE, or NVLink).

Comment: [This](https://developer.nvidia.com/gtc/2019/video/S9139) may be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

You have to upload the overlap regions to both devices. You can't (easily) read values from another device, so you have to duplicate and pad at least some of the input values as required. `iSize` is obviously not enough input size when accessing `iSize + 2` different input values.

If this were a multi pass algorithm, you would need to explicitly perform a copy of relevant regions in between passes.

Try modeling data dependencies formally on paper when attempting to target multi GPU systems.

Both GPUs can access memory allocated with `cudaMallocHost`, but it's usually not advisable to use that memory type as performance over PCIe bus is pretty bad compared to device local memory. There is also driver managed memory, but that isn't suited for two GPUs sharing the same active working set either.